# Cannot login with new password after resetting using SqlMembership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, roleprovider, sqlmembershipprovider

After resetting the password using SqlMembership provider.I am unable to login with the new password.
Below is the line of code used to reset the password for dbo.aspnet_Membership table.
Password is encrypted .
Everytime I reset the password a new encrypted value is stored inside the table.
But unable to login.

My webconfig setting:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
<providers>
<clear />
<add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"    connectionStringName="xxxx" applicationName="xxxx" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

C# code:

```
Membership user= Membership.GetUser(txtUser.Text);
user.ResetPassword(txtNewPassword.Text);
```

Can anyone help me with this.Why I can't still login with the new password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResetPassword` is not actually the function you should be using for setting a new user password. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d94bdzz2(v=vs.110).aspx

`ResetPassword` is for generating a new random password (imagine a forgot my password link).  The constructor you're using (string) isn't for the *new* password, it's for answering a secret question if applicable.

The method you should actually be using is `ChangePassword`. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.changepassword(v=vs.110).aspx

You'd consume that similar to:

```
Membership user= Membership.GetUser(txtUser.Text);
user.ChangePassword(oldPasswordString, txtNewPassword.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.bUt here the problem is I dont have the password then what will be solution.?How can I chnage the password without knowing the old Value.Even there is no security question in aspnet_Membership table.It is a null value.

Comment: Well, you could chain the methods ResetPassword (it returns a string of the newly set password) then ChangePassword, first argument of old password pass in the return value of reset value.  Boom!

Comment: It worked fine in local instance .But when I tested in Production it is throwing "User account has been locked out although "IsLocked" column of Aspnet_Membership table value is "0".