# Cannot login with new password after resetting password using ASP Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have similar to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675391/cannot-login-with-new-password-after-resetting-using-sqlmembership-provider), but I am using ASP Identity with token-based authentication.

After **resetting** or **setting** new password, PasswordHash in my user's table updates, but user is not able to log in with new password until restarting the service where Web-Api is hosted.

in my AccountController:

```
// POST api/Account/ChangePassword
[Route("ChangePassword")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordBindingModel model)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
    }

    IdentityResult result = await this.UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(this.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>(), model.OldPassword,
        model.NewPassword);
    IHttpActionResult errorResult = this.GetErrorResult(result);

    if (errorResult != null)
    {
        return errorResult;
    }

    return this.Ok();
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordBindingModel model)
{
    if (model.UserId<= 0 || model.Code == null)
    {
        return this.BadRequest();
    }

    IdentityResult result;

    try
    {
        result = await this.UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(model.UserId, model.Code, model.Password);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
    {
        return this.InternalServerError(exception);
    }

    IHttpActionResult errorResult = this.GetErrorResult(result);

    if (errorResult != null)
    {
        return errorResult;
    }

    return this.Ok();
}
```

In ApplicationOAuthProvider:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    try
    {
        var user = await this.userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            this.logger.Info("Invalid grant for {0}", context.UserName);
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        var oAuthIdentity =
            await this.userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, context.Options.AuthenticationType);

        var cookiesIdentity =
            await this.userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        var properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);

        context.Validated(ticket);

        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);

        this.logger.Info("User '{0}' is signed in.", user.UserName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        throw;
    }
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem. The problem was in the userManager in ApplicationOAuthProvider. I used the same instance of UserManager each time. The working code is:

```
    public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly string publicClientId;

    private IKernel kernel;

    private readonly Logger logger;

    public ApplicationOAuthProvider(string publicClientId, IKernel kernel, Logger logger)
    {
        if (publicClientId == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("publicClientId");
        }

        if (kernel == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("kernel");
        }

        if (logger == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        }

        this.publicClientId = publicClientId;
        this.kernel = kernel;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var userManager = this.kernel.Get<UserManager<User, int>>();

            var user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                this.logger.Info("Invalid grant for {0}", context.UserName);
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            var oAuthIdentity =
                await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, context.Options.AuthenticationType);

            var cookiesIdentity =
                await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            var properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);

            context.Validated(ticket);

            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);

            this.logger.Info("User '{0}' is signed in.", user.UserName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```